# How to declare a singlecast delegate in C#

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

Is there a way to declare a singlecast delegate in C#? E.g. so that it would not be possible to have more than one method referenced by the delegate at a single point in time.

I am thinking about a way to achieve flexibility in choosing what implementation to use at runtime, but with some kind of safeguard to prevent multiple actions being triggered to avoid any side-effects, especially with non-void return type delegates.

Comment: Are you looking for `Action<T>` (or if you want to return some value `Func<T>`)?

Comment: AFAIK you cannot, quite simply; any delegate you declare (or are likely to ever meet) will be multi-cast. There's also no good way to *check* whether it has multiple targets (without allocating)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to encapsulate the delegate creation and assignment. Then you can throw an exception if there are more than one handlers. Here's a trivial example

```
using System;
public delegate int MyDelegate(int x, int y);

public class Wrapper{
    private MyDelegate d;
    public Wrapper(){
        this.d = null;
    }
    public void Assign(MyDelegate func){
        if(d!= null && d.GetInvocationList().Length > 0){
            throw new Exception("No more than 1 handlers allowed");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Assigned");
        this.d+= func;
    }
}
public class Program
{
    static int Sum(int x, int y)
    {
        return x + y;
    }
    static int Difference(int x, int y)
    {
        return x - y;
    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        Wrapper w = new Wrapper();
        w.Assign(Sum);
        w.Assign(Difference); //throws Exception;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the delegate must be an Event. *(for example interface implementations etc)*

You could use the custom event accessor [add/remove](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/add). **This only works at runtime**, so this cannot be detected compiletime.

Here's an example:

```
private EventHandler _myHandler;

public event EventHandler MyHandler
{
    add
    {
        if (_myHandler != null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Only one eventhandler is supported");

        _myHandler = value;
    }
    remove
    {
        // you might want to check if the delegate matches the current.
        if (value == null || value == _myHandler)
            _myHandler = null;
        else
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Unable to unregister, wrong eventhandler");
    }
}
```

---

And just use it as a normal event:

```
MyHandler += (s, ee) => Console.WriteLine("MyHandler handler");

// if you're lazy, you could support deregistering with null
MyHandler -= null;
```

It's even possible to use `Func<T>` instead of `EventHandler`